# Using sum() in mysql and getting multiple lines

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    D009_Valor_Custo_Unitario
FROM 
  D074 
  LEFT JOIN D001 ON D001_Id = D074_D001_Id_Composicao 
  LEFT JOIN D049 ON D001_Id = D049_D001_Id 
  LEFT JOIN D009 ON D049_Id = D009_D049_Id 
  LEFT JOIN D037 ON D037_Id = D001_D037_Id 
  LEFT JOIN D074A ON D074_Id = D074A_D074_Id 
WHERE 
 D074_D001_Id = '55963' 
  AND 
  D009_C004_Id = '1'
```

Which gives me 16 lines with the cost of each product.

I need to add all those costs to a total and bring this total together with the cost of each product.
I've tried this:

```
SELECT
  sum(D009_Valor_Custo_Unitario) as `Custo Unit.`,
  D009_Valor_Custo_Unitario
FROM 
  D074 
  LEFT JOIN D001 ON D001_Id = D074_D001_Id_Composicao 
  LEFT JOIN D049 ON D001_Id = D049_D001_Id 
  LEFT JOIN D009 ON D049_Id = D009_D049_Id 
  LEFT JOIN D037 ON D037_Id = D001_D037_Id 
  LEFT JOIN D074A ON D074_Id = D074A_D074_Id 
WHERE 
 D074_D001_Id = '55963' 
  AND 
  D009_C004_Id = '1'
```

But it gives me only one line with the sum of all the costs and the unit cost of the first product.
I need something like that:

```
| Total    | Unit cost |
| -------- | --------- |
| 5        | 2         |
| 5        | 2         |
| 5        | 1         |
```

How can I do it in mysql ?
Thanks !

Comment: you need `GROUP BY product_id`